# How to Enable TCP/IP for mssql instance in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, sqlcmd

I'm not able to connect SQL Server hosted in Ubuntu 16.04 using my program, I believe its because the TCP/IP is disabled for the instance I try to connect (Protocols for SQLEXPRESS under SQL Server network configuration).

How I'm sure because I tried to connect my program to SQL Server that hosted in Windows and it able to connect.

Example my instance name is SQLEXPRESS, so I'm trying to connect through SSMS by using IP Adress\SQLEXPRESS and it fails. But I am able to connect to the SQL if I use IP address only as the server name.

I tried to search about sqlcmd for enable the tcp/ip but all of them just show the guide to change the ports.

So, how can I enable tcp/ip connection for ip\SQLEXPRESS instance in Ubuntu 16.04?

picture below just an example on enabling tcp/ip for the sql instance in windows

[image: The setting in windows sql server configuration]

Comment: `ip address\instance name` is wrong way and won't work. You need to configure instance listen on some other port and then access it by `ip address,port` without instance name.

Comment: so i can tell that for SQL SERVER in ubuntu we cannot access like that is it?

Comment: Can you access win based sql server by `ipaddress\instancename`? I don't think so, unless that instance runs on default port, then maybe. And no, you can't tell anything about ubuntu - I just noted that your idea combining IP address and Instance name may not work with SQL server at all.

Comment: Disagree on unable to connect SQL server with ipaddress\instancename , i can show you my connection to using that method. 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/16kkiNahYZGeGYEvw5bKA00xuT32dxTIO/view?usp=sharing
checkout above link for the image, testing connection using ODBC tool

Comment: Hmm, your example is on internal network; maybe it is not using TCP/IP to connect after all :) It may be using other protocols or services to query SQL server data. Ubuntu may not support those services. Anyway, configure your SQL instance to listen on spcific port and connect to that port - you should access your instance this way easily.

Comment: Alright @Arvo, now able to listen if i use ip,  or ip, port.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason why this doesn't work on linux is because it doesn't have a SQL Server Browser application that Windows has available. This application redirects the requests to 1433 to whatever random port it's listening to currently -- this is why it will only connect when the port is specified. In my case this stinks because I'm having to work around an ancient application that we don't have the source code for. I'm thinking about writing a little application that will redirect the default traffic to the correct port for linux msssql.